# Failing Razor IF Statement (for VB Application)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not sure of the correct syntax for the following Razor code (for a VB App):

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30035: Syntax error.

Source Error:

```
Line 20:                 <br />
Line 21:                 @If (ViewBag.vejpEdit.Equals(Nothing)) Then
Line 22:                 {
Line 23:                     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "AdditionalDivData", New With {.id = currentItem.AddDataId, .projId = ViewBag.ProjId, .divisionControllerName = ViewBag.DivisionControllerName, .divisionName = ViewBag.DivisionName, .vejpEdit = False}, New With {.class = "divisiontransitionbutton"}) |
Line 24:                 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need delete brackets `{` and `}`

Comment: no. i tried it with and without the {}s.  Mike provided the correct answer below. thanks still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing VB and C# syntax. This is the correct VB version:

```
@If ViewBag.vejpEdit Is Nothing Then
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "AdditionalDivData", New With {.id = currentItem.AddDataId, .projId = ViewBag.ProjId, .divisionControllerName = ViewBag.DivisionControllerName, .divisionName = ViewBag.DivisionName, .vejpEdit = False}, New With {.class = "divisiontransitionbutton"}) 
End If
```